# Get the variables list from shapely library

Tags: python, shap

I'm using shap library to get the variables importance the issue I'm having is that I only find plots options but I need to get a list of the variables importance in order.

Answer (score 0):

Every `*Explainer` class has method `shap_values` that returns a list of MxN numpy arrays, where `M = # objects`, `N = # features`.

Variable importance is measured by `mean(|SHAP value|)` as stated in the [repo's README](https://github.com/slundberg/shap). So if your data is in a pandas dataframe, here's how to get importance-sorted features list:

```
per_feature_mean_shap = np.abs(shap_values[0]).mean(axis=0)
df.columns[np.argsort(per_feature_mean_shap)]
```